# How to pass parameters by value to javascript functions from c# with Gekofx

Tags: c#, javascript, parameters, gecko

One can always invoke javascript like this:

> mybrowser.Navigate("javascript:YourJavascriptFunction('yourArgument1', 'youArgument2')");

Mine is single Argument as comma separated string, say "110.1,2.2,24,55.5"

**HTML has JS function quoted below**.

How to ensure that logger gets **array[1]=2.2** and **array[2]=24**. Removing single quotes '' around Argument, HTML behaves as if logger received nothing.

Whereas with single quotes '' around Argument **included**; it seems logger received "Argument" as text-string . This is verified by splitting the Argument in C# and then passing two separate Arguments.

> ```
>   function logger(msg){           
>                             var array = msg.split(',');
>                             V1g.refresh(array[1]);
>                             I1g.refresh(array[2]);
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it might help other at some point in time:

> geckoWebBrowser1.Navigate("javascript:logger('Argument0','Argument1','Argument2')");

needed to be replaced with :

> geckoWebBrowser1.Navigate("javascript:logger('" + Argument0.ToString() + "','" + Argument1.ToString() + "','" + Argument2.ToString() + "')");